# TextView in nested (ConstraintLayout --> LinearLayout) visible only in editor

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

A TextView contained inside a ConstraintLayout contained inside a LinearLayout is only visible in Android Studio's Preview window.

The TextView is constrained to the start and top of the parent, so it should be placed in the top-left corner of the View. All three views are set to fill the parent's size.

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_downloads"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"> <!-- default -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_downloads"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Hello World!" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I expect to see "Hello World!" placed in the top-left corner of the screen, as shown in the [Preview window here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88GGR.png), but instead I see a blank View, as shown in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4m2g.png), taken from a minimal example using the "Empty Activity" project template and the layout shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
android:text="Hello World!"
```

instead of

```
tools:text="Hello World!"
```

I guess Android Studio has stopped giving these kinds of warnings.

**Note:** `tools:text` is only for use in the layout editor to label things

**Another Note:** You can use `TextView.setText()` in your activity as an alternative.

Comment: Right, thanks, forgot they're separate properties after replacing a resource with the literal. I'm fairly certain the same issue was occurring before I switched out the resource though

Comment: On second thought, this might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983459/

Comment: @HewwoCraziness I do not see this as a duplicate. The problem here is that you used the `tools` namespace.

Comment: Nevermind. You might be right.

Comment: Switching to the Android namespace worked. Thanks. (Marked as duplicate.)

Comment: Of course! No problem.